# Can you perform an action at 5 seconds into playing a sound file using Sound.js?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, soundjs

I have my sounds created and playing my html5 page ok on all devices.
I have some animations that I want to reveal when the audio reaches certain points.
maybe at 5, 10 , 25 seconds.

Is that possible if so can you provide sample code to call a function at a certain time interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this very simply using setTimeout():

```
// Set up functions that will be triggered during sound playback...
var a = function(){
    console.log("Do something after 5 seconds");
}

var b = function(){
    console.log("Do something after 10 seconds");
}

var c = function(){
    console.log("Do something after 25 seconds");
}

// Play the sound...
createjs.Sound.play("page1");

// Immediately after playing the sound, trigger the time out functions...
setTimeout(a, 5000);  // Triggers after 5 seconds of playback
setTimeout(b, 10000); // Triggers after 10 seconds of playback
setTimeout(c, 25000); // Triggers after 25 seconds of playback
```

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/aaronmarruk/2yoqpm8L/)

More information on setTimeout can be found here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

> setTimeout
>
> The syntax is: var timerId = setTimeout(func|code, delay)
>
> func|code – Function variable or the string of code to execute.
>
> delay – The delay in microseconds, 1000 microseconds = 1 second. The execution
>   will occur after the given delay.

Comment: How would i use that with my code to play my sound? createjs.Sound.play("page1"); page1.setTimeout(a,5000); ?

Comment: As an alternative, for more advanced sequencing, it would be possible to use TweenJS: `createjs.Tween.get().wait(5000).call(a).wait(5000).call(b).wait(15000).call(c);` The main advantage being that you can pause the tween with your sounds, and keep them synched.